# How can I download directories and files from an FTP server using Perl?

Tags: perl, ftp

1. I need to download the list of files and directories from FTP server. 
   I have connected the FTP server through [Net::FTP](http://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aFTP) module. In that I have changed the working directory using `cwd` method. 
   The current working directory in the FTP contains files and directories, which I carry the lists in an array. From that array I need to identify the directory and files. I need to segregate the file and directory from the array before I am downloading those to the local.
2. How to set the local path of the downloaded file?

Can any one please provide solutions/suggestions for the issues I outlined above?

Comment: Isn't the answer to 2 really obvious if you just glace at the `get` method on the page you linked to?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to all your suggestions and solutions. Finally I have found a solution.
Using Net::FTP::File module we can find/segregate the directories and files from the repository of ftp server, which we are going to download. I have shared the lines...

```
use Net::FTP;
use Net::FTP::File;

my $ftp=Net::FTP->new("hostname");
$ftp->login("username","password");
$ftp->cwd("/repository_name");
my @ftp_lists=$ftp->ls("/repository_name ");

foreach my $ftp_file(@ftp_lists){
push @ftp_dirs, $ftp_file if($ftp->isdir($ftp_file));
push @ftp_files, $ftp_file if($ftp->isfile($ftp_file));
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to vote on the answers that were helpful.  Generally you would accept the most correct one and the post above would be added as an edit to your original post.  If none of the responses solves the question then you can post your own answer and accept it but doing so does not award any points to you or your solution contributors.

Answer (score 3):

For identifying files and directories, you may have to parse the return value of `$ftp->ls`. As for setting the path of the downloaded file, the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::FTP) indicates:

> `get ( REMOTE_FILE [, LOCAL_FILE [, WHERE]] )`
>
> Get `REMOTE_FILE` from the server and store locally. `LOCAL_FILE` may be a filename or a filehandle. If not specified, the file will be stored in the current directory with the same leafname as the remote file.

Comment: I have used the above code that you have mentioned. For an example, my @ftp_files_list=$ftp->ls("/tarun"); Just I want to identify the directories and files from the array.

Comment: Excellent. Now, you can post what is returned by `$ftp->ls`. You have the output, we don't. I don't even have access to a plain FTP server anymore.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your suggestions. I have shared the solution along with, which I have worked out.

Answer (score 2):

I know you're asking using `Net::FTP`, however I was trying to do the same thing and ended up using `wget` instead as a command from a system call from inside Perl to download all files (an entire website actually) to my local drive, then I (from another system call) moved those files to where I wanted them as `wget` created a folder structure starting from the root so I had to `mv` them to somewhere else. The code looks something like this (you'll have to test it for your setup and get the directories correct):

```
my $username = "tim";
my $password = "asdfghj";
my $domain   = "example.com";
my $get = `wget -P /var/www/$domain/ -m ftp://$username:$password\@$domain/httpdocs`;
my $mv  = `mv /var/www/$domain/httpdocs/* ../`;
my $del = `rm /var/www/$domain/httpdocs/`;
```

Sorry it's not `Net::FTP`, but it's much faster and less frustrating to do if you need a whole lot of files, you can get more control with `Net::FTP` for sure … I run this from a web app and use it to move entire websites from one server to another and know it works a charm :)

Comment: Regarding how does wget fall short? It is quite limiting in that you can't easily browse directories on the server and then decide if you want to get particular files or not. Net::ftp is excellent if you want to have absolute control of everything you can do I guess. - What specifically is your end goal?

Comment: You can limit files and directories to with wget, it's in the documentation.. another drawback with wget is that if it's not your server and it's not installed then you will have to ask the admin to install it...

Comment: your solutions is much helpful. The thing is I am devloping perl script in windows. I am developing a tool to download listed files, which the user mentioned in the text file or a log file. Before downloading the files from the ftp, I need to segregate the directories and files. Simply I would like to take the directories names and files names in a repository(which I am going to download from) of the FTP.

Comment: Well using wget for windows http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/wget/1.11.4-1/wget-1.11.4-1-setup.exe/download you can download a certain directory, the `$get` variable should contain the files that it downloaded, you could easily parse this into filenames if you wished. To do this, you would start with `wget -nv ... ` to your  command. Some documentation is here, and a reference to using `-r` for recursion is also explained: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html (I'm off to bed!)